# Wordpress get_categories count number is not correct

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a strange behaviour. I'm reading the number of posts with the get_categorie function. But for some categories it shows a false number.
Example Category XY (3) but it only has one Post and not three.
The number of the total posts is correct. Anyone an idea what the problem might be? Thanks in advance

```
if ( ! empty( $categories ) ) {
 $categories_args['slug'] = explode( ',', $categories );
}

$filter_categories = get_categories( $categories_args );

$filter_html = '';
$filter = isset( $filter ) ? $filter : 'none';
if ( $filter == 'category' AND $type != 'carousel' ) {
// $categories_names already contains only the used categories
if ( count( $filter_categories ) > 1 AND $query_args['post_type'] == "post" ) {

    $count_posts = wp_count_posts();
    $published_posts = $count_posts->publish;
    $classes .= ' with_filters';
    $filter_html .= '<div class="g-filters ' . $filter_style . '"><div class="g-filters-list">';
    $filter_html .= '<div class="g-filters-item active" data-category="*"><span>' . __( 'All', 'us' ) . '<span class="subText"> ('.$published_posts.')</span></span></div>';

    foreach ( $filter_categories as $filter_category ) {
        $filter_html .= '<div class="g-filters-item" data-category="' . $filter_category->slug . '"><span>' . $filter_category->name . '</span><span class="subText"> ('.$filter_category->count.')</span></div>';
    }
    $filter_html .= '</div></div>';
 }
}
```

Comment: Can be the case that you have Category and Child categories ? if you have the tick box on the Category and Child Categories the same post counts 1 on both (category and child category).

Comment: Hi josedasilva, thanks for your reply. I don't have child categories on them. It's also strange that in the database in the table [prefix]_term_taxonomy the count column has the same value as shown on the homepage. How is the count column working?